# How to use the function CONCATENATE with IMPORTRANGE?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I have two spreadsheets documents:

- [Libro1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lIpak48SxPpi4aWo20_BuquZ12zCQXekwSCEyBcYotQ/edit), with a sheet name "Dia1"
- [Libro2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hRemDihjX-fOOnYPoKFK7Zo3TTVJlZ7W7nzaIErRFYo/edit), with a sheet name "Consolidado"

I use without problem the function IMPORTRANGE in the "Libro2" for get the value of cell A1 in the sheet "Dia1" of "Libro2".

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1lIpak48SxPpi4aWo20_BuquZ12zCQXekwSCEyBcYotQ";"Dia1!A1")
```

Rta: 150

Now, I want to make the function IMPORTRANGE as a concatenation with the aim to make it parameterizable in the same sheet.

F1="Dia1" //In the cell F1 is the value for concatenate;

I tried:

```
=CONCATENAR("=IMPORTRANGE(""1lIpak48SxPpi4aWo20_BuquZ12zCQXekwSCEyBcYotQ"";""";F1;"!A1"")")
```

and although the concatenation is right the result,   `=IMPORTRANGE("1lIpak48SxPpi4aWo20_BuquZ12zCQXekwSCEyBcYotQ";"Dia1!A1")`
is a string.

[image: Result as a string]

**Question:**

How to set the string concatenate for the desired behavior with the result (`150`)?

Original question in: [SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/31765/1184).

Comment: This question was crossposted to [es.so]. See http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31765/c%C3%B3mo-utilizar-la-funci%C3%B3n-concatenar-con-importrange-en-google-hoja-de-c%C3%A1lculo

Comment: Thanks @Rubén, I added the reference ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1lIpak48SxPpi4aWo20_BuquZ12zCQXekwSCEyBcYotQ";"'"& F1 &"'!A1")
```

Comment: It Works con &! Thank you.

Comment: Single quote/apostrophe it's not required.